# How to delete and reconnect lines in a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I made a mistake while I was experimenting clipping and merging polygons and now I have lines that I do not want in my polygon. How can I delete lines which make up the polygon and then connect the gaps?

I would like to get rid of the three lines within this polygon and reconnect the lines at each corner of the triangle.

[image: polygon with unwanted lines.]

Comment: you're on the right track, but first you need to break the polygon into polygons: - Vector>Processing geometry>Division of composite objects...

Answer (score 3):

I would use **Reshape Featuers** tool in the `Advanced Digitizing Tool` to fill the gap, then **Dissolve** these three polygons.

1. Activate `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` and switch to `Edit Mode` to use **Reshape Features** tool.
2. Select one of the polygons and enlarge it, so that the gap is fully covered.

[image]

3. Select three polygons and use **Dissolve** tool (in the `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`.

[image]

Comment: I can see what you mean about the three seperate polygons. However, for some reason, they are not three seperate polygons, it is being treated as one (even though they have been separated along the way). Therefore, the dissolve tool is not working...